# LINQ two SQL GroupBy adjust translation

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I am trying understand why when I add this `GroupBy` in  it adds this section to the translation `GROUP BY and OUTER APPLY`. Is this the correct way to do group by in L2S or should it be something different? I wanted to make the optimize sql query.

```
return DateList.GroupBy(p => new { p.DataIdMain, p.DataIdNumeric,p.DataIdAlt }).Select(x=>x.First()).ToList();
```

sp profile

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t13].[test], [t13].[DataIdMain], [t13].[DataIdNumeric], [t13].[DataIdAlt], [t13].[Title] AS [DataTitle], [t13].[GroupTitle], [t13].[GuideLineTitle], [t13].[value] AS [ExternalDiseaseId], [t13].[DiseaseName], [t13].[VersionKey], [t13].[value2] AS [AgentVersionKey], [t13].[Name] AS [AgentName], [t13].[RxNormTallMan] AS [AgentRxNormTallMan], [t13].[NccnTallMan] AS [AgentNccnTallMan], [t13].[Modified], [t13].[value3] AS [Added], [t13].[Id]
FROM (
    SELECT [t5].[DataIdMain], [t5].[DataIdNumeric], [t5].[DataIdAlt]
    FROM (
        SELECT [t0].[DataIdMain], [t0].[DataIdNumeric], [t0].[DataIdAlt], [t4].[VersionKey] AS [value], [t0].[IsCurrentVersion], [t0].[Status]
        FROM [dbo].[Datas] AS [t0]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[DataList] AS [t1] ON [t0].[Id] = [t1].[DataId]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[DataParts] AS [t2] ON [t1].[Id] = [t2].[RegimenId]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[DataEntries] AS [t3] ON [t2].[Id] = [t3].[RegimenPartId]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[DataAgents] AS [t4] ON [t3].[AgentVersionKey] = [t4].[VersionKey]
        ) AS [t5]
    WHERE ([t5].[value] = @p0) AND ([t5].[IsCurrentVersion] = 1) AND ([t5].[Status] = @p1)
    GROUP BY [t5].[DataIdMain], [t5].[DataIdNumeric], [t5].[DataIdAlt]
    ) AS [t6]
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (1) 1 AS [test], [t12].[DataIdMain], [t12].[DataIdNumeric], [t12].[DataIdAlt], [t12].[Title], [t12].[GroupTitle], [t12].[GuideLineTitle], [t12].[value], [t12].[DiseaseName], [t12].[VersionKey], [t12].[value2], [t12].[Name], [t12].[RxNormTallMan], [t12].[NccnTallMan], [t12].[Modified], [t12].[value3], [t12].[Id]
    FROM (
        SELECT [t7].[DataIdMain], [t7].[DataIdNumeric], [t7].[DataIdAlt], [t7].[Title], [t7].[GroupTitle], [t7].[GuideLineTitle], [t7].[ExternalDiseaseId] AS [value], [t7].[DiseaseName], [t7].[VersionKey], [t11].[VersionKey] AS [value2], [t11].[Name], [t11].[RxNormTallMan], [t11].[NccnTallMan], [t7].[Modified], [t7].[Added] AS [value3], [t7].[IsCurrentVersion], [t7].[Status], [t7].[Id]
        FROM [dbo].[Datas] AS [t7]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[DataList] AS [t8] ON [t7].[Id] = [t8].[DataId]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[DataParts] AS [t9] ON [t8].[Id] = [t9].[RegimenId]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[DataEntries] AS [t10] ON [t9].[Id] = [t10].[RegimenPartId]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[DataAgents] AS [t11] ON [t10].[AgentVersionKey] = [t11].[VersionKey]
        ) AS [t12]
    WHERE ([t6].[DataIdMain] = [t12].[DataIdMain]) AND ((([t6].[DataIdNumeric] IS NULL) AND ([t12].[DataIdNumeric] IS NULL)) OR (([t6].[DataIdNumeric] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t12].[DataIdNumeric] IS NOT NULL) AND ((([t6].[DataIdNumeric] IS NULL) AND ([t12].[DataIdNumeric] IS NULL)) OR (([t6].[DataIdNumeric] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t12].[DataIdNumeric] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t6].[DataIdNumeric] = [t12].[DataIdNumeric]))))) AND ((([t6].[DataIdAlt] IS NULL) AND ([t12].[DataIdAlt] IS NULL)) OR (([t6].[DataIdAlt] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t12].[DataIdAlt] IS NOT NULL) AND ((([t6].[DataIdAlt] IS NULL) AND ([t12].[DataIdAlt] IS NULL)) OR (([t6].[DataIdAlt] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t12].[DataIdAlt] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t6].[DataIdAlt] = [t12].[DataIdAlt]))))) AND ([t12].[value2] = @p0) AND ([t12].[IsCurrentVersion] = 1) AND ([t12].[Status] = @p1)
    ORDER BY [t12].[DataIdMain], [t12].[DataIdNumeric], [t12].[DataIdAlt]
    ) AS [t13]
ORDER BY [t13].[DataIdMain], [t13].[DataIdNumeric], [t13].[DataIdAlt]',N'@p0 uniqueidentifier,@p1 int',@p0='34D59934-12CA-40FB-95F7-26DC7AB32FF8',@p1=7
```

Comment: How do you want the generated SQL to change?  What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: Do I need the 4 sub query's ? can I just do it with one

Comment: How would you do it with one?  Write the query out that you want it to generate instead.

Comment: You're asking if this is the correct way to do GroupBy in LINQ. Yes it is. How any ORM decides to translate the statement into SQL is largely beyond your control. You won't be able to make it generate the query *you* like. So in fact this is a simple yes/no question and the answer is: yes it's correct.

Comment: @GertArnold There are often multiple ways of writing a query to generate the desired results, not all of which will result in the same SQL or the same performance.  Saying that you have no influence over the executed SQL is false.  You don't have *complete* control, but you don't have *zero* control.  There are absolutely situations where you can alter your LINQ query to ensure the desired SQL is generated.  Whether this is one of those situations depends on information not provided.

Comment: @Servy I know, therefore "*largely* beyond your control". And the LINQ query is correct. The question seems to go in the direction "how can I write my LINQ query to make it generate this SQL statement" but that would require a SQL statement, obviously, and detailed knowledge of the class model, all of which I don't see. Hence the only possible answer so far: yes, it's correct. Maybe if OP changes direction we can do more, although I doubt it.

Comment: Also, it would be interesting to see the query behind `DateList`.

Comment: @GertArnold Saying that the question doesn't provide enough information for you to give an answer, as justification for providing an incorrect answer, doesn't make any sense.  If the question doesn't contain enough information to provide an answer then *say that* or ask for the information you need, rather than providing an incorrect answer